# How to show process completion icons in front of every process based on ajax call coming from server?

Tags: extjs

I have a view having  accordian, Inside it I have several process(p1,p2,p3) named in grid like structure
I want to give click able icons in front of all the process depending upon the result coming from ajax call(server).Process can be successful(should be shown in green color bar icon), on going (shown in yellow color bar), fail ( shown in red color bar).

How should I do it?

It will be helpful if code snippet will be there?

Comment: Where do you want this icon? On in front of title on accordion?

Comment: Icon will be in front of each process(p1/p2/p3) inside the accordian depending upon the process status

Comment: In that case you should provide some code. The best would be demo on fiddle.

Comment: You can refer the demo code [http://jsfiddle.net/Abhinav11/qhrkhan9/4/] when this view is loaded I have status for each process (success/running/failed) depending on this, click able icon should be displayed in status column of the grid.

Comment: Idea is row should look like [http://s1378.photobucket.com/user/abhinavbhardwaj07/media/demo_status_zps5ac7cb33.png.html?1417702585430&1417702586943] with in the grid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve clickable icon in grid is by using `actioncolumn`. You can define multiple buttons in such columns, so you can define all 3 and hide this which aren't required.

Example column definition:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    dataIndex: 'status',
    items: [
        {
            icon: 'url_to_success_icon',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                // do something
            },
            getClass: function(value) {
                return value == 'success' ? '' : 'x-hide-display';
            }
        },
        {
            icon: 'url_to_running_icon',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                // do something
            },
            getClass: function(value) {
                return value == 'running' ? '' : 'x-hide-display';
            }
        },
        {
            icon: 'url_to_failed_icon',
            handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                // do something
            },
            getClass: function(value) {
                return value == 'failed' ? '' : 'x-hide-display';
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/kxq00ft5/1/